# Calculate working days and weekends on date

Tags: c#, datetime

I am new here and want to ask my first question

My plan is to add to todays date +2 days, but skip weekends and business days.

I already found this code:
https://github.com/Opturne/WorkingDaysManagement/blob/master/DateManagement/WorkingDayHelper.cs

And with it I can already skip Saturday and Sundays. But somehow it ignores the holidays.

I use it like that:

```
var listHolidays = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2021,09,15),
    new DateTime(2021,09,16),
};

var helper = new WorkingDayHelper(listHolidays);

var newDate = helper.GetNext(DateTime.Now);
```

As result I get todays date (15th of September), which means it ignores the listHolidays.

Is there a error in the code, or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be to do with the fact that `DateTime.Now` returns a date AND time?  Should you be using `DateTime.Today`, which return a DateTime of today with the time portion as midnight.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem